# Error in argument number or types when calling Oracle procedure or function with parameters using Spring Data

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, spring-data

The stored procedure is being called, as well as the REST controller, as follows:

Stored Procedure:

```
FUNCTION LOGIN(P_COD_SIS         IN  VARCHAR2,
           P_COD_OPA             IN  VARCHAR2,
           P_USERNAME            IN  VARCHAR2,
           P_PASSWORD            IN  VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER;
```

Repository method:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "PKG_WEB_BENEF.LOGIN")
public Integer login(
        @Param("P_COD_SIS")  String systemCode,
        @Param("P_COD_OPA")  String operatorCode,
        @Param("P_USERNAME") String username,
        @Param("P_PASSWORD") String password
);
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "Login.LOGIN",
                procedureName = "PKG_WEB_BENEF.LOGIN",
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_COD_SIS", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_COD_OPA", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_USERNAME", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_PASSWORD", type = String.class)}, resultSetMappings = "mapping")})
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "mapping", classes = {@ConstructorResult(targetClass = Login.class, columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "returnValue", type = Integer.class)})})
public class Login implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String username;

    private String systemCode;
    private String operatorCode;
    private String password;
    private Integer returnValue;
```

Then, when I execute method `login`, Oracle raises the error *PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'LOGIN'*. What was the mistake?

P.S.: I'm using **Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE**, **Hibernate 5.2.12.Final** and **Oracle 12.1.0.2**.